# Angular front end does not recognize json response as an array

Tags: angular, spring

While doing official Angular tutorial, I tried to make a real backend connection instead of mock Angular "server", using Spring JPA REST.  REST endpoint is configured as PagingAndSortingRepository. Here is a server response from backend.
[image: Server response]

I try to get this data into front-end as follows:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/heroes';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService ) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl); // of(HEROES);
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
      <span class="badge badge-dark">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code produces following error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: Please show your html code

Comment: yes please show html and where you consume `getHeroes()` method

Answer (score 1):

The response from server contains _embedded as an object. Either you need to send it as array of "heroes" or on front end have heroes variable and assign it as

```
this.heroes = response._embedded.heroes;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

HTML use the async pipe

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of getHeroes()|async">
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

get only heroes property from the response object using map operator.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<any>(this.heroesUrl)
        .pipe(
            map(data => data._embedded.heroes)
        );
}
```

Comment: Property _embedded does not exist on type Hero[]

Comment: Despite of error it works, thanx. But what is the reason for async?

Comment: @Dmitry The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. check the link
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating an object `{}` in `*ngFor`. You should iterate over an array `[]`

Suppose your json is saved in `data`
Based on your json, it should be something like:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of data._embedded.heroes">
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```